# Make navbar active on url and any url's following from it

Tags: django

I am trying to make my navbar element active if the user is on the current url and any url's leading from it.

For example, I want the navbar to be active on:

http://example.com/products
AND
http://example.com/products/discounted-items

I was using this:

```
{% if url_name == 'products' %}active{% endif %}
```

and was very happy till I realised that once I progress from the 'products' page to 'products/discounted-items' it would cease being active.

Is there a clean way to do this in django?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could do `if 'products' in url_name`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you could simply do the following:

```
{% if 'products' in url_name %}active{% endif %}
```

Be aware that this also causes `/productsfoobar` to be active.

To prevent that you could use `products/` instead of checking it without the trailing-slash.

Comment: Thats perfect. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

In case (as i seen the page) if u are using Bootstrap u can add "active" in the class field in nav